# SQL issue - how do I select all tuples which contain all references in a second table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-optimization

Heres the deal - I have three tables here:

```
Companies:
ID | NAME | DETAILS

TAGS
ID | TAGNAME

TAGS_COMPANIES
COMPANY_ID | TAGID
```

Using a nested query I can retrieve all companies that are tagged by tags in a certain set i.e:

```
select c.* from companies c where c.id in (select t.company_id where t.tagid in (12,43,67))
```

The above query returns all companies that have an either tag id 12, 43 or 67 but I need to retrieve all companies who are tagged 12 AND 43 AND 67

How would I redo my query here? I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too efficient but works:

```
select c.* 
from companies c 
where c.id in (select t.company_id from tags_companies t where t.tagid = 12)
and c.id in (select t.company_id from tags_companies t where t.tagid = 43)
and c.id in (select t.company_id from tags_companies t where t.tagid = 67)
```

Another possibility using a HAVING clause:

```
select c.id, c.name, c.details
from companies c join tags_companies t on c.id = t.company_id
where t.tagid in (12, 43, 67)
group by c.id, c.name, c.details
having count(distinct t.tagid) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

With one subquery.

```
select c.* 
      from companies c  
      where (c.id, 3) in 
         (select t.company_id, count(distinct t.tagid) 
                 from tags t
           where t.tagid in (12,43,67) 
             group by t.company_id)
```

magic number 3 means different tags count.